# Orphaned Domain in Windows Forest - Unable to Connect to Cluster in Hyper-V Failover Cluster Manager

Tags: windows, active-directory, hyper-v, failovercluster

Have a question here that pertains to an orphaned domain, specifically trying to connect to a Hyper-V cluster in Failover Cluster Manager.

We have a Windows forest with a root domain of domain.tld. Inside the forest there are 4 domains, something.domain.tld, other.domain.tld, etc., each with multiple domains except for one. So, other.domain.tld has just a single domain controller.

The domain controller for other.domain.tld is corrupt and will not boot, and following all the recovery methods put forth by Microsoft in their technet and community forums we are unable to recover the NTDS database. Also tried following a number of blogs and guides found on the Internet. Unfortunately, there are no backups of the server or checkpoints from prior to the server becoming corrupted.

The corrupted DC is hosted on an accessible Hyper-V cluster.

Within the other.domain.tld domain there are 2 Hyper-V compute-nodes which are connected to connect using Failover Cluster Manager, with a SAN as the storage-node. The cluster is currently running multiple VMs, but I am unable to connect to the cluster since both ADDS and DNS for the other.domain.tld domain is currently not available. Logging into the compute-nodes as a local admin also does not grant me the ability to admin or connect to the cluster. The cluster DNS address is also unknown at this time, as the previous technical team missed some items in their documentation processes.
[rough cluster layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZN3H.png)

This is a mutli-part question:

1. Can I disjoin the Hyper-V hosts from the current inaccessible domain and join them to a working domain without losing the cluster
2. Is it possible to disconnect the VMs from the cluster so they are not managed by the cluster
3. For the storage, should I expect any issues if I follow through with #1, or will the cluster storage still be available if I move the Hyper-V machines to a new domain and setup a new FCM cluster

I know how to purge orphaned domains within Windows Active Directory, just need to get to the point I can.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Unfortunately, you cannot.  If the domain is gone, the cluster is too.  The cluster stores critical information inside the domain computer objects.  If the domain is gone, this is unrecoverable.

Question 2: Yes, you should still be able to view and manage the virtual machines inside Hyper-V Admin somewhat.  Whatever host they are currently on will have all the required data.  You may have trouble removing them from the cluster directly, but the most important part is the VHD/VHDX files.  Those can be lifted from the VMs when they are shut down and you can recreate the VMs.  Two ways to go about this.

- You can actually try to just copy the entire VM config, VHDs and all, and put them on another Hyper-V server.  From there, you can import the VM in the Hyper-V manager.  It will probably ask you to map the virtual NICs and the VHDs.  If that works, you can then as a second step import them (Configure Cluster Role -> Virtual Machine) into the new cluster inside the cluster manager.
- You can also just create a new VM but attach the existing VHDs.  The big disadvantage here is you lose the device IDs on the virtual NICs so you have to go back and potentially reconfigure the VM network configuration.
- In either case, if you were using nested BitLocker or shielded VMs or other advanced encryption/protection, you have to export the required certificates from the old Hyper-V host and import it into the new Hyper-V host.

Question 3: N/A, I think, due to the answer in Question 1.  :-(  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you Conure, found you are correct about 1. Was able to disjoin one of the cluster members and join it to the root domain. One of the issues I ran into was while joining into root domain was a duplicate SPN; ended up having to rename the server to join the root domain.

After joining to the root domain I was able to connect to the iSCSI storage and see the VMs. Just a matter of registering them in the host, and then following suit with the rest of the hosts.

Tried to upvote your answer, but I need more reputation to do so.